# authorization for chainlink node v2 api

Tags: chainlink

i'd like to work with the chainlink v2 api to automatically adding jobs after creating a chainlink node. using curl this works well for health

```
curl localhost:6688/health
```

but not for protected endpoints like

```
curl localhost:6688/v2/jobs
```

which returns {"errors":[{"detail":"Authentication failed"}]}

what is the auth implemented for the chainlink node?
tried basic auth with curl using the node admin credentials which didn't help...

Answer (score 2):

chainlink node auth can be done via sessions.

1. use curl with session endpoint to create cookie
2. use the cookie to authorize endpoint access

to create a cookie in file ./cookie

```
export USERNAME=<chainlink admin user name>
export PASSWORD=<chainlink admin user password>
curl -c ./cookie -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"email":"'${USERNAME}'", "PASSWORD":"'${PASSWORD}'"}' localhost:6688/sessions
```

the cookie can now be used to access protected api endpoints

```
curl -b ./cookie -c ./cookie localhost:6688/v2/jobs
```

Comment: Wow! This is great information!

Comment: chainlink node account management via api:

-  list ether accounts: `curl -b ./cookie -c ./cookie http://localhost:6688/v2/keys/eth`
- import account `curl -b ./cookie -c ./cookie -d @keystore-file.json http://localhost:6688/v2/keys/eth/import?oldpassword=<keystore-password>`
- delete account `curl -X DELETE -b ./cookie -c ./cookie http://localhost:6688/v2/keys/eth/<account-id>?hard=true`

Comment: It doesn't seem like these URL endpoints are working for me - playing back the payload works well even though I use ``--cookie-jar`` and ``--cookie``. Did these URLs change recently?